# Regular Expression for Version

Tags: regex

I want a Regex for version that accepts this format:

```
##.##.##
```

====

but that doesn't accept

> 00.00.00

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a regex factory. Attempt to learn regex. It is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only 00.00.00 is not acceptable, then you can use the following regex

```
00\.00\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|00\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)\.\d{2}|(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)\.\d{2}\.\d{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your regex dialect supports negative lookahead assertions `(?!...)` this is easy:

```
^(?!00\.00\.00$)(\d{2}\.){2}\d{2}$
```

If your regex dialect does not support `?!` and/or `\d`, please update your question with pertinent details and/or tags.

Comment: Then tell us which regex dialect you are using so we can attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression could look like this:

```
(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)\.(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)\.(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)
```

(`\d` is a digit, `\.` is a dot, `[1-9]` is a digit from 1 to 9)

explanation in detail:

- `0[1-9]` will match numbers from 01 to 09
- `[1-9]\d` will match 10 to 99
- `(0[1-9]|[1-9\d)` will match either 01 to 09 or 10 to 99 (so any number from 01 to 99)

these will be accepted:

```
01.01.01
11.11.11
55.55.55
55.01.33
10.20.30
```

these will not be a match:

```
00.01.01
00.00.00
44.33.00
```

http://regex101.com/r/lE7uH6